# Can hadoop be used as a distributed queue server?

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing

I'm thinking of learning hadoop but not sure if it'll solve my problem.  Basically I have a job with a queue and a bunch of workers.  Each worker does a small amount of work and then either saves the results(if successful) or sends it back to the queue for further processing.  My problem is scalable, is limited by the bandwidth on the network(ec2) which will never keep up with multiple cpu's crunching the data.  I thought maybe I could run my jobs in Java in a hadoop cluster and have hadoop distribute the work via a queue.  Would this be a better approach? I am correct in assuming hadoop can a queue and try to run jobs as locally as possible to minimize bandwidth usage and maximize cpu usage? My program is very cpu bound but most of my recent problems with its performence are related to passing work over a network(I want to keep the work as local as possible), but the difference between the hadoop tutorials I see and my problem is that in the tutorials all the work is known in advance while my program is generating new work for its self constantly(until its finally done).  Would this work and would it help me reduce the impact of passing messages over a network?

Sorry I'm new to hadoop and wanted to know if it could solve my problem.

Comment: @PurplePilot I'm actually using rabbitmq right now. But my work is very small(but alot of it) and I'm noticing transferring work over the network is delaying my work(get max 200-300mb/s throughput and my cpus process the work faster then the network can send it).  I'm trying to see if there's something that would keep the work as local as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is all about running jobs in a batch-like mode over a large data set. It's hard to get it to have some sort of queue-like behavior, but not impossible. There is Apache ZooKeeper, which will give you synchronization to build a queue if you need it.

There are plenty of tools to solve the problem it looks like you are trying to solve. I suggest taking a look at [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). If you use python, [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) is quite fantastic.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  I am currently using rabbitmq(its great but because I have several billion small work items, the network overhead is getting high as bandwidth is limited).  The problem is delays passing data over the network to do work.  My work is a batch job but it can do each item very quickly, I'm trying to see if my program creates an work item would it stay local to be processed or would it transfer it over the network?

Comment: basically, Rabbitmq solves my problem but I'm trying to get a similar type feature that reduces network IO.

Comment: The file still needs to be ingested into Hadoop, which it will move over the network 3x for replication. Then, it will process over it locally. There is enough overhead in this process that you are probably still better off. Basically, if you want to do anything FAST in Hadoop, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: yikes, your right.  Sorry not to sound like a pest but is the process still the same if its not a file.  Basically my queue just has numerical data that is calculated(its not a file or anything, would that still get replicated? ).  Using rabbitmq, I can scale out very easily but I cannot scale up(since if each core can process 100 mb/s and my limit is 200mb/s then I waste resources with anything above 2 cores). My idea was(now I'm thinking its wrong) was to have hadoop distribute the initial work and then each node submits new tasks to its own local task scheduler.

Comment: Yea, i just think it's going to be hard to coerce Hadoop into doing stream-like processing. The basic use case is load file into hadoop, then run mapreduce job. You can probably coerce it into what you are trying to do, but its probably going to be more work than just building a custom solution.

Comment: Thanks orangeoctopus. I hope hoping hadoop did it this automatically. I'll do some more reading and study how tasks are distributed and maybe I can find a similar use case as mine. I think the key to solving my problem is to distribute tasks locally and only replicate when needed(which queues don't do), I'll keep digging and maybe I figure a different way of thinking of the problem. Thanks(and I read on your profile your putting out a book on mapreduce, I def. can't wait to read it).

Comment: Good luck, if it isn't hard it isn't worth doing! Good luck with your problem.